# Array modifier with some kind of scaling transform for each iteration

Tags: modifiers, objects, scale

I have just used an array modifier to create a bunch of stairs for a pyramid we're creating. I have made the railings for the staircase wider at the bottom than it is at the top and therefore my stairs don't fit perfectly, so I was hoping there's a way to use the array modifier to incrementally scale the stairs so they fit. Please see screenshot for reference.

[image: The pyramid]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put the array under the control of another object (here, an empty,) by checking 'Object Offset' Then any object-level transform on the empty will be applied to each instance in the array.

In this example, X runs across the steps, and Z is up. The empty has been scaled in X.

[image]

This gives a step-wise taper. The progression is geometric, not arithmetic, though.

If you wanted a linear progression, you could make each step out of two halves: assign a 'Mirror' modifier after the array,  checking 'Clip' and 'Merge', In this case, instead of scaling the empty, translate it  a little in X. This would have the effect of translating the two halves toward one another by a constant amount, each step.

If you want the taper to be continuous, *don't* do as above. Instead, leave the array as it was and assign another modifier: 'Simple Deform' > Taper. Select the appropriate axis for the taper.

By default, the taper acts on *both* axes orthogonal to the taper direction. Lock off any axis you want to remain unaffected.. in this example, Z.

[image]

(The empty in the second illustration is redundant; I've used the step's own axes.)